# What is the meaning of negative exponents in SI units?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Please could someone explain the reason for using negative superscripts in SI units, and more precisely when to use negative versus positive?

I do not understand, for example, why the volume of a fuel would be given in m<sup>3</sup> but heat of combustion would be given in J m<sup>-3</sup>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative exponents means **per**. In countries that were heavily influenced by the British, units such as meters per second would most likely be written $m/s$. In Europe and elsewhere it could be written with negative exponents as $m.s^{-1}$.

In your example $J m^{-3}$ means joules per cubic meter.